# SAT solving with more than 2^32 clauses

Tags: c, integer-overflow, sat-solvers, sat

I'm trying to solve a big **CNF formula** using a `SAT solver`. The formula (in [DIMACS](http://www.satcompetition.org/2009/format-benchmarks2009.html) format) has `4,697,898,048 = 2^32 + 402,930,752` clauses, and all SAT solvers I could find are having trouble with it:

> - [(P)lingeling](http://fmv.jku.at/lingeling/) reports that there are "too many clauses" (i.e. more clauses than the header line specifies, but this is not the case)
> - [CryptoMiniSat4](http://www.msoos.org/cryptominisat4/) & [picosat](http://fmv.jku.at/picosat/) claim to read the header line as saying 402,930,752 clauses which are 2^32 too few
> - [Glucose](http://www.labri.fr/perso/lsimon/glucose/) seems to parse 98,916,961 clauses and then [reports to have solved the formula as UNSAT](http://pastebin.com/VRmRVcLA) using simplification, but this is
>     unlikely to be correct (an initial segment of the formula this short
>     is very likely to be SAT).

Is anyone aware of a SAT solver that can handle files this large? Or is there something like a compiler switch that can sidestep this sort of behaviour? I believe all solvers are compiled for **64bit linux**. (I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to handling numbers this big, sorry.)

Comment: Maybe you can try a distributed SAT-solver.

Comment: Are these OSS? You could modify them to use 64b integers.

Comment: @Jeff: yes, they are all open-source C or maybe C++, don't know how to tell the difference.

Comment: Doesn't matter. Integer types are the same :-)

Comment: Building with 64-bit ints isn't likely to do much good in the end, because DPLL-based solvers are notoriously bad on really large SAT instances.  Stochastic solvers are better but even among those I've never heard of one tackling a formula with over four billion clauses.

Comment: Is it possible to separate the set of clauses into subsets with disjoint variables? What is the maximum number of literals per clause?

Answer (score 6):

I'm the developer of CryptoMiniSat. In most cases where the CNF is so huge, the issue is not the SAT solver but that the translation of the original problem into CNF wasn't done carefully enough. I assume you didn't write that CNF by hand -- you had a problem which you translated to CNF using an automated tool.

The act of translating a problem into CNF is called encoding and it has a huge literature in academia. It's a whole topic to itself, or more appropriately, whole topics to themselves. Please see the research papers on Constraint Programming (CP), Pseudo-boolean constraints (PB), ANF-to-CNF translation techniques (see crypo workshops/conferences) and electronic circuit encoding (search for AIG, Tseitin encoding and its variants and look at the references). These are the big topics but there are many others. Taking a peek at these will reduce your CNF by at least 3 orders of magnitude, probably more.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. For my specific problem, the only way to a smaller equivalent encoding appears to me by obtaining relatively deep insights about symmetry breaking and I'm pessimistic they exist. All of the more expressive specification languages you mention would not allow for a more concise encoding in this case: my problem is quite naturally expressed in CNF, and in particular none of the variables are redundant (up to unit propagation and potential symmetries) -- it just happens that I'm looking for a massive object.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not sure it's naturally expressed in CNF, given that it takes more than 4 billion clauses express it. You could probably express the Apple A8 chip with that many clauses, and that is a very complex system that took tens of thousands of engineer-years to design. I suggest you look at alternate ways of expressing your problem.